# Initialize new Hash Table, pointers issue

Tags: c, hashtable, chaining

I have this exercise for homework that follows:

Consider the following definition to represent dynamic hashtables with collision treatment chaining.

```
typedef struct entry{
   char key[10];
   void *info;
   struct entry *next;
}   *Entry;

typedef struct hashT{
   int hashsize;
   Entry *table;
}   *HashTable;
```

Define `HashTable newTable(int hashsize) 
note that the memmory necessary must be allocated and that all table entrys must be initialized with empty list.

My proposition is this:

```
HashTable newTable(int hashSize){
   Entry *table = malloc(sizeof((struct entry)*hashSize));
   HashTable *h = malloc(sizeof(struct hashT));
   h->hashSize = hashSize;
   h->table = table;
   return h;
}
```

im pretty sure the logic is correct. my problem is with pointers. for example, sometime I see (char *), or in this case (table *) before the malloc function... Is this necessary?

and for the return, should I return h, or *h? and whats the difference?

thank you

Comment: Try compiling with warnings enabled. You should be seeing errors. Hiding pointers in typedefs is usually bad for the exact reasons seen here. For example `Entry *table` is a pointer to pointer to struct entry, yet you try to allocate space for `sizeof (struct entry) * hashSize`, though that too is misparenthesized.

Comment: This is C basics. What does you C book say about pointers and structures? What is not clear about its explanation? Did you check another textbook/resource? Ask you teacher? And never ever `typedef` a pointer to data types, it is worst practice and causes bad style!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,

```
Entry *table = malloc(sizeof((struct entry)*hashSize));
```

will be

```
Entry table = malloc(sizeof(struct entry)*hashSize);
                           ^^^    
                           Look at the parentheses here.
```

Also you will do the same change over here,

```
HashTable h = malloc(sizeof(struct hashT));
```

Same goes with `HashTable`. You forgot that you have hidden the pointers inside `typedef` which you shouldn't.

With the above mentioned changes the code will be

```
HashTable newTable(int hashSize){
   Entry table = malloc(sizeof(struct entry)*hashSize);
   HashTable h = malloc(sizeof(struct hashT));
   h->hashSize = hashSize;
   h->table = table;
   return h;
}
```

And **Dont hide pointer behind typedef**.(Wish I could write this in red color but yes this will save you from many many problems).

#### What is the type of `Entry*`?

It is of type `struct entry **`. Here in your case you don't need it while allocating. It will be an overkill if you do so.

#### What is the difference between `h` and `*h`?

Well typewise `h` is of type `struct hashT**` and so `*h` will be of type `struct hashT*`.

#### What shall you do next?

- Compile all your code with warnings enabled. `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`
- Check the return value of `malloc`.
- Free dynamically allocated memory when done working with it.
- Read [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
- Grab a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).